# how to create a quiz countdown timer for each question

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, countdown, countdowntimer

I want to create a countdown timer for a quiz that will reset on the next question and also go to the next question if the time runs out and the player has not chosen a answer. Can anyone help me create this plz?

```
var counter = 10;

setInterval(function () {
  counter--;

  if (counter >= 0) {
    id = document.getElementById('count');
    id.innerHTML = counter;
  }
  if (counter === 0) {
    id.innerHTML = 'Times Up!';
  }
}, 1000);
'''
```

Comment: What's the problem? What did this do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic working code for you. Play around with it to get your desired result. Happy coding!

```js
var counter = 10;             //Time counter
var questionsCount = 0;       //Questions counter

//Questions array
var questions = [
   "Question 1","Question 2","Question 3"
] 

questionDivId =  document.getElementById('question');

setInterval(function () {
    counter--;

    if (counter >= 0) {
        id = document.getElementById('count');
        id.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
        id.innerHTML = 'Times Up!';
        counter = 10;
        questionsCount++;
    } 
    
    //To check if all questions are completed or not
    if (questionsCount === questions.length){
        questionDivId.innerHTML = "Well Played! Game is over";
        id.innerHTML = "";
    } else{
        questionDivId.innerHTML = questions[questionsCount];
    }   
}, 1000);

//To go to the next question
function goToNextQuestion() {
    questionsCount++;
    counter = 10;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1 id="question"></h1>
    <h1 id="count"></h1>
    <button onclick="goToNextQuestion()">Next</button>
</div>
```